# How do i get JSON object into servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, json, servlets

Basically I have an HTML file in which I create a JSON object:

```js
    function CreateJson() {
        var tableObj = [];

        var loopCounter = 0;
        var inputValues = [];

        var table = document.getElementById('inputTable');
        for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
            for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
                loopCounter++;

                inputValues.push(table.rows[r].cells[c].firstChild.value);

                if (loopCounter == 3) {
                    tableObj.push({
                        model : inputValues[0],
                        colour : inputValues[1],
                        year : inputValues[2]
                    });
                    loopCounter = 0;
                    inputValues = [];
                }
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: { tableObj : JSON.stringify(jsondata)},
            url : 'ServletUrl',
            timeout : 5000,
            success : function(data, textStatus) {
                // whatever
            },
            error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // whatever
            }
        });
    }
```

I have a form with an `action` to my Java servlet, and when I submit the form, the JavaScript code above gets executed. How do I retrieve and parse the JSON object inside of my servlet? The JSON object being `tableObj`.

EDIT:
I edited my CreateJson function:

and in my servlet I have:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {

        Object json = request.getParameter("tableObj");
        System.out.println(json);
```

In the logs it prints null.

Comment: I dont understand your question. TableObj is a json object? Do you want to get it  in the servlet? You send it?

Comment: how do I send tableObj to the servlet. I want to work with tableObj inside my servlet

Comment: did you try posting it to servlet, using for example jquery? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: do you have some servlet code implemented? please show us in order to make an accurate answer

Comment: Either you change your $.ajax() type into 'GET' or copy and paste the same code inside your doGet() into doPost() in your servlet.

Comment: I changed it to type : 'GET', but my doGet function still returns null

Answer (score 0):

See you are using POST in your java script

```
$.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: { tableObj : JSON.stringify(jsondata)},
            url : 'ServletUrl',
            timeout : 5000,
            success : function(data, textStatus) {
                // whatever
            },
            error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // whatever
            }
        });
```

but you are no using the same verb **(doPost)** in your servlet, please change

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
```

**to**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
```

Comment: you can't change doGet() to doPost() in Servlet implementation. You must have both methods declared.

Comment: what I was trying to said is that hi is reading the value in doGet, instead of that he must read it in doPost, and you are right both method belong to the same Interface...

Comment: I changed it to type : 'GET', but my doGet function still returns null.